# Append Seq[Column] to existing Spark dataframe Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, sequence

I have Spark Dataframe `df_data` and Seq[Column] `Metrics`. I am trying to append the columns from Seq[Column] to existing Dataframe. Seq[Column] will have multiple columns.

I was able to append single column to Dataframe. But not able to proceed with Seq[Column]

```
  val new_df = Metrics.foldLeft(df_data)((df_data, newColumn: (Column)) =>
              df_data.withColumn("column_name", newColumn))
```

I have not worked much in Seq. Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr
val new_df = df_data.select((expr("*") +: Metrics) :_*)
```

if the brackets are needed etc. will depend on spark/scala version.  It's worth avoiding with_column in folds/loops as the projections created aren't always optimised out.

Comment: I believe this logic will fail if there is no column/columns in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have hardcoded the column name in `.withColumn("column_name", newColumn)` every time a column is appended, it overwrites the previously added column by the name of "column_name"

If you use a map (or a Seq of tuples if you wish to maintain ordering) to define column names and their values at the same time.

```scala
val Metrics = Map("c1" -> lit("one"), "c2" -> lit("two"))

val new_df = Metrics.foldLeft(df_data) { 
  case (df, (colName, colVal)) => 
    df.withColumn(colName, colVal) 
}

new_df.show()
```

Original dataframe `df_data`:

```
+---+---+
|  x| x2|
+---+---+
|  0|  0|
|  1|  2|
|  2|  4|
|  3|  6|
|  4|  8|
+---+---+
```

New dataframe `new_df`:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  x| x2| c1| c2|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|one|two|
|  1|  2|one|two|
|  2|  4|one|two|
|  3|  6|one|two|
|  4|  8|one|two|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `Map(columnName -> columnValue)` then you can use `withColumns` function to append columns to existing spark DataFrame.

```
scala> val df = Seq("Srinivas").toDF("firstName")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [firstName: string]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)


scala> val newColumns = Map("lastName" -> lit("Reddy"), "age" -> lit(30))
newColumns: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Map(lastName -> Reddy, age -> 30)

scala> df.withColumns(newColumns).printSchema
root
 |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = false)


scala> df.show(false)
+---------+
|firstName|
+---------+
|Srinivas |
+---------+


scala> df.withColumns(newColumns).show(false)
+---------+--------+---+
|firstName|lastName|age|
+---------+--------+---+
|Srinivas |Reddy   |30 |
+---------+--------+---+
```